# filesystem based emberjs app

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm building a filesytem based emberjs-app. But unfortunately the security won't allow me to push stuff to the history (see e.g. [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=301210) but i guess that applies to all browsers).

setting the locationtype to none is fine, but I would still like to utilize the back and forward buttons and urls of the browser.

Is there a way to configure this (maybe setting the base-url to index.html, without rewriting the build process)?

**edit**

I call the url from my browser like this: file:///path/index.html.

in my routes.js and fileroute.js I've got this workaround:

```
// routes.js
export default Router.map(function() {
   // this route only redirects to main
   this.route('fileroute', {path: 'index.html'});
});
// routes/fileroute.js
// only for running app on filesystem
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
       this.transitionTo('fileroute.projects');
    }
});
```

So I guess each hash-change would already effect the files-url

```
file:///path/#differentroute
also for
file:///path/#index.html/childRoute
```

Comment: You should still be able to use the hash routing on the filesystem?

Comment: true, but I guess it's the way ember handles the base-url (I added some remarks above)